# Show element does not put it back inside parent element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a multi-step form which hides the last `<fieldset>` and shows the next `<fieldset>` when the next button is clicked. But when the previous button is clicked the bottom of the `<div>` which contains these `<fieldset>` goes up to the next element as if the `<fieldset>` doesn't exist.

How do I make the parent element continue to wrap around the child element when the child element is shown?

```
<fieldset>
    <h4 class="site-yellow">Category</h4>
    <h6 class="text-muted">The category of the test</h6>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-4">
            <label>Select Category</label>
            <select id="categories" name="categories" class="form-control">
                {% for category in form.category %}
                {{ category }}
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-default"
           value="Previous"/>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-warning" value="Next"/>
</fieldset>
```

```
$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    previous_fs.show();

    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {

            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            opacity = 1 - now;

            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        },

        duration: 800,
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        },

        easing: 'linear'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I decided to do was to adjust the height of the parent container when the previous button is clicked; I get the `previous_fs` height and set the css of the parent container to that:

```
var bottom = previous_fs.offset().top + previous_fs.outerHeight(true);
$("#main-container").css("height", bottom);
```